# Bringing prescription drugs to Turkey

Tags: transit

I will be traveling to Istanbul for two days before boarding a cruise ship. Will I be able to enter with the following prescription drugs, in small amounts, and a letter from my doctor authorizing me to use them?

1. Risperidone (prescribed for bipolar disorder)
2. Clonazepam (prescribed for anxiety)
3. Levothyroxine Sodium (prescribed for thyroid disorder)
4. Teriparatide (with injection needles, prescribed for osteoporosis)

Comment: Turkey is not drug friendly: see https://4kgroup.com.tr/en/permitted-drugs-at-turkish-airports/#:~:text=According%20to%20Turkish%20airport%20laws,of%20the%20need%20for%20medicine.  But enforcement might be lax: see also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173900/traveling-from-the-u-s-to-turkey-with-prescription-medications-adderall-rital

Comment: Could not find anything better than https://gumrukrehberi.gov.tr/page/s-it-possible-for-passenger-to-bring-along-th which states (you’ll have to scroll past the list of questions) that with a prescription/letter from your doctor it should be OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173900/traveling-from-the-u-s-to-turkey-with-prescription-medications-adderall-rital